# mempool data lost after raising maxmempool and restarting

Tags: mempool

I'm running bitcoind 24.0.1 and changed maxmempool from 1000 to 2000 because I don't want to drop txs (I'm running an explorer) then I restarted bitcoind.

Just before restart getmempoolinfo reported this:
"size":           395462,                                                                                                                                                                                                   "bytes":       176566561,
"usage":       986487264,                                                                                                                                                                                               "maxmempool": 1000000000,

On shutdown I caught this message: Dumped mempool: 1.33008s to copy, 12.6878s to dump
AFAIK this should indicate the mempool has been written to disk as is the default setting.

After restart getmempoolinfo reported this:
"size":             4351,                                                                                                                                                                                                     "bytes":         1535793,                                                                                                                                                                                                 "usage":         7678800,
"maxmempool": 2000000000,

Why did the mempool data not persist?

Comment: It should persist, but it may take a few minutes to load the mempool data again after restart, as all transactions get re-verified when loading them back.